# PHP error handler throwing exceptions that are not being caught

Tags: php, exception, php-7.1

I've got some error handling code that is trying to make sure that I catch and handle any problems at a certain level, so I've used `set_error_handler` to convert recoverable errors into exceptions and then I have a catch for all exceptions.  Idea being that whether the code hits some recoverable error, or throws an exception, this should catch all of it.  But, what I'm seeing is that a retriable error is happening, being converted into an exception and then not caught by my catch. Don't understand why.

```
public function catchableFatalErrorCatcher($errno, $errstr) : bool
{
    if (error_reporting() !== 0 && $errno === E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR)
    {
        throw new ParseException($errstr, $errno); //extends \Exception
    }
    return false;
}

public function evaluate($cmd)
{
    $prevErrorHandler = set_error_handler([$this, 'catchableFatalErrorCatcher']);
    try
    {
        $tokens = $this->tokenize($cmd);
        $value  = $this->parse($tokens, $this->model);

        if (is_array($value))
        {
            // IN THE FAILURE CASE, $value IS AN ARRAY OF OBJECTS AND THIS 
            // CAUSES AN ERROR BECAUSE THE ELEMENTS CAN'T BE TURNED INTO STRINGS.
            $value = implode(', ', $value);
        }
        return strval($value);
    }
    catch (ParseException $e)
    {
        if ($this->trace !== null)
        {
            $this->trace .= $e->getMessage() . "\n";
        }
        return '';
    }
    finally
    {
        set_error_handler($prevErrorHandler);
    }
}
```

I end up with an HTTP error 500 on my site, and in my php error log the message: `PHP Warning:  Uncaught <<redacted>>\ParseException: Object of class <<redacted>> could not be converted to string`. The stack trace clearly shows that the error handler is being called because of the implode call I've noted above. How is this not being caught!?

Answer (score -2):

```
## Please Use Below code
public function catchableFatalErrorCatcher($errno, $errstr) : bool
{
    if (error_reporting() !== 0 && $errno === E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR)
    {
        throw new Exception($errstr, $errno);
    }
    return false;
}

public function evaluate($cmd)
{
    $prevErrorHandler = set_error_handler([$this, 'catchableFatalErrorCatcher']);
    try
    {
        $tokens = $this->tokenize($cmd);
        $value  = $this->parse($tokens, $this->model);

        if (is_array($value))
        {
            // IN THE FAILURE CASE, $value IS AN ARRAY OF OBJECTS AND THIS 
            // CAUSES AN ERROR BECAUSE THE ELEMENTS CAN'T BE TURNED INTO STRINGS.
            $value = implode(', ', $value);
        }
        return strval($value);
    }
    catch (Exception  $e)
    {
        if ($this->trace !== null)
        {
            $this->trace .= $e->getMessage() . "\n";
        }
        return '';
    }
    finally
    {
        set_error_handler($prevErrorHandler);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to that code - what have you changed, and why?

Comment: php provide Exception 
Please read  How to use Exception from this link (https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

Comment: Please add all explanations to your answer, not to the comment section

Comment: ok, I have give a code of default functionality php so i have not give explanations

Comment: I haven't heard of such a rule before - please ensure that other people can learn from your answer. This is only possible if you **explain** what that code does. As the OP already used some working code, he should know about the differences and why these differences are neccessary

Comment: I don't know, and I don't want to guess. Have you tried reproducing the original problem with the original code and found it fixed after changing it to your code?

Comment: How is this different from what I was doing?  If it wasn't clear, my `ParseException` extends `Exception`, so I don't see why this would be any different.  Also, I have previously tried catching `Exception` and `Throwable` and have tried throwing `Error` as well.  (Possibly not all combinations of that.) Would this make a difference.  I agree with Nico, please explain why your code works and what is wrong with mine.

Comment: BTW, tried your changes.  I changed my code to throw and catch `\Exception` directly and it did not fix the problem.